# How do I remove a file from CVS?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project, cvs, delete-file

I am a long-time code developer, but relatively new to IntelliJ Idea.

Within a web service project I deleted a CSS file and was immediately prompted to remove the file from CVS. I answered "No" until I could finish factoring out the old css from my web source files. I later processed an "Update Project..." from Version Control to merge my completed changes, and the removed CSS file was restored from the CVS repository.

I know there is the manual method of removing a file from CVS via the command line, but I would like to know if there is a quicker method to do this via the CVS plugin within IntelliJ Idea after the initial "delete from CVS?" dialog box has been skipped.

Background info:

- IDE: IntelliJ Idea 8.1.4
- Language: Java 1.6
- OS: Windows XP SP3
- Source control: CVS

Thank you!

Comment: you mean delete from version control but keep it locally?

Comment: @Saintali, sorry, I did mean delete the file from version control so that it reflects the current deleted state of the local file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a "commit changes", the deleted files will be removed from the CVS. There is a Version Control view if I can remember on the lower side of the screen, where you can see your changes. Sorry, I used Idea quite some time ago only, but I hope you will be able to find it...

Comment: I will give that a try. Unfortunately, my commit was delayed until probably tomorrow due to another developer having precedence over merging his code into the project. I miss git already. ;)

Comment: @Jake Then you might have to try in several turns... I would try to commit _only the deleted files_ in the first commit, because after that, you can update the others, which are not up to date in one go, and you'll have a much easier life (at least for this 20 minutes, that is :) )